# Avoid Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I have the following two functions:

```
    private object[] GetFormatedDataArray(
            Dienstleistungsreservierung dlres,
            KostenstellenProvider kstProvider)
        {
            SAPKonto konto;
            try { konto = KontierungsProvider.Instance.GetSAPKonto(dlres); }
            catch { konto = new SAPKonto(); konto.KontoText = "UNBEKANNT"; }

            Kostenstelle kst = kstProvider.GetKostenstelle(dlres.Raumreservierung.Buchung);
            KostenstellenValidator.Validate(kst);

            return new object[] {

                dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.KonfStandort,
                dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner.AnsprechPartnerName,  

       ......

}
```

There is a possibility that the value of:

```
dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner
```

is null, for that i have done a if clause around the which creates the .csv file, that he should create the file if the value is null or != null.

With that function/ returning values of that function i create a .csv file.

```
 {
       .....
        var file = GetCsvFile(dl, accDate);
                    // CSV werden auf Platte geschrieben!
                    var csvWriter = new CSVWriter(file);
                    csvWriter.WriteLine(GetHeader());

                    foreach (Dienstleistungsreservierung dlres in dlDic[dl])
                    {
                        if (dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner == null || dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner != null)
                        {
                            csvWriter.WriteLine(GetFormatedDataArray(dlres, kstProvider));
                        }
                    }
                    csvWriter.Flush();

    ....
    }
```

But the Error is still there? Is there a other way to get around?

Comment: Eh. Null or not null is binary set, your if will always be true! take out the == null bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner == null || 
    dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner != null)
```

Your `if` statement contains **contradictory** check. If there is a possibility that the value of `dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner` can be null then you should check if its not null then proceed. Something like following

```
if (dlres.Raumreservierung.VirtualRaum.Etage.Gebaeude.Partner != null)
```